# How to select specific course by selecting course id and concatenate users all selected course with in same row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, subquery

I am joining users table with selected_course table and course table with selected_course, my requirement is  I want to get  those users with course_id=2  and in same row select using concatenation  of all courses which is selected by user.

user table

```
id   name
1     user_1

2     user_2
```

user_education_details

```
id      user_id  education_id  selected_course  

1        1          1               2

2        2          1               2

3        1          2               4

4        3          1               2


5        3          2               4
```

Actual Requirement:

```
user_id   required_course     user_all_courses    course_name


1             2                      2,4            a,b

2             2                      2               a

3             2                     2,4             a,b
```

Using codeigniter query format:

```
$this->db->select('users.*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('selected_course sc','c.user_id=users.id');
$this->db->join('course c','c.id=sc.selected_course');
$this->db->where('sc.selected_course',$course_id=2);
$this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HAVING` clause is what you're looking for. To filter data based on a group use this clause.

```
SELECT 
    ued.user_id, 
    2 AS required_course,   -- passed course id
    GROUP_CONCAT(ued.selected_course) AS user_all_courses, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) course_name
FROM user_education_details ued
INNER JOIN courses c ON ued.selected_course = c.id
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(IF(selected_course = 2, 1,0)) > 0;

Output:

| user_id | required_course | user_all_courses | course_name | 
| 1       | 2               | 4,2              | b,a         | 
| 2       | 2               | 2                | a           | 
| 3       | 2               | 2,4              | a,b         |
```

You can also order `user_all_courses` and `course_name` by using a `ORDER BY` clause inside `GROUP_CONCAT`. Here is one example.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(ued.selected_course ORDER BY selected_course ASC) AS user_all_courses,
```

Now you can quickly convert this to your equivalent CodeIgniter query.

Check this working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/212818/2/0) for the same.

Comment: thanks a lot for your valuable answer,could you please suggest me how to write perfect mysql queries (creative way) sometimes Getting stuck  while writing queries

Comment: I'm also here for learning, participate in such questions for mysql and everyday you'll learn by looking at answer of other guys or by understanding queries from othere.

Comment: still if you want some specific question, you can let me know. Happy to help

Comment: little problem here, getting user_id=4 and user_id=5 but this users don't have course id=2

Comment: run this query in your database, it will not include user_id = 4 and 5. If does, please check both of them would be having selected_course as 2

Comment: i've added a fiddle, you can verify over there. It is returning expected data.

Comment: can u please check js fiddle link which u have posted I have updated field with user_id=4 but this should not come in result because userid=2 have course_id=4  not 2

Comment: I mean required_course for user_id=4 should be empty.

Comment: if you've done any changes, it will create a new link. You have to share new link to see the changes.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/212818/1 please follow this